# Java database connection with protected table

Tags: java, connection

I'am connecting my application to a Microsoft Access DB. The problem is that every table of this database is protected by a password(because the data in the table are imported from MS share point). Every time I try to execute a query by using a Statement object it ask me user and password. Is there a way to pass automatically user and pwd and avoid to insert them every time?

Answer (score 2):

try out this

```
final String fileName = "c:/myDataBase.mdb";
Connection con = null;
try {
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    String url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ="+fileName;
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"username","password");
} catch (Exception e) {

    // Handle exceptions
    ...
} finally {
    try { if(con!=null) {con.close();} } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

Comment: In this way you pass user and pwd for connecting to database: my db is not protected, the tables are

Answer (score 1):

You can supply the username and password in the JDBC connection string.

Comment: Do you mean the string like "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=myDB.accdb" ?